# How to define range in importxml formula in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, web-scraping, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

In my google sheet, I have URL in A1 and other data in B1, C1, D1, E1, etc... I want to use importxml formula but want to this work automatic, I mean in column B2 I try this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( IMPORTXML($A1&$B1:$CZ1, "//suggestion/@data"))
```

so its do the rest of the job automatic I mean fetch data for A1and B1 in B2 and do A1 and C1 in C2 and A1 and D1 in D2, is it possible? I mean now I have to do manually enter formula in every column. hope you understand what I mean.

```
Column A   | Column B    | Column C
=================================
site.com   | Name 1      | Name 2
           |             |  
           |             |  
           |             |
```

---

```
Column A   | Column B    | Column C
=================================
site.com   | Name 1      | Name 2
           | =ARRAYFORMULA( IMPORTXML($A1&$B1:$CZ1, "//name/@data"))  
           |             |  
           |             |
```

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet or url and example of scraped values?

Comment: I tried to replicate it but no luck. sheet would be great

Comment: @player0 did you find anything, I just want to tell in more detail like this formula =iferror(query(A:D, "where B = 'Date' ",0),"no submission yet")  i just need to enter formula in only H7 and its automatic put values under I7, J7,K7 . I don't need to insert values or formula for I7, J7,K7  same thing I want for importxml formula. hope you got my point .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IMPORTXML` is not supported in `ARRAYFORMULA` as you expect it. your options are:

- paste in **B2** and drag the formula to the right

  ```
  =IMPORTXML($A1&B1, "//suggestion/@data")
  ```
- paste in **B2** the hardcoded formula for all columns:

  ```
  ={IMPORTXML(A1&B1, "//suggestion/@data"),
    IMPORTXML(A1&C1, "//suggestion/@data"),
    IMPORTXML(A1&D1, "//suggestion/@data")}
  ```

  [image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

or scripted solution:

```
function onOpen() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var length = sheet.getRange("B2:2").getValues().filter(String).length;
    sheet.getRange("C3:3").clearContent();
    sheet.getRange("C3:3" + length).setFormula(sheet.getRange("B3").getFormula());
    sheet.getRange("C4:1000").clearContent();
    }
```

where cell **B2** is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1&B1:D1)
```

and cell **B3** is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IMPORTXML(B2:2, "//suggestion/@data")))
```

[image: 0]